# Click event in if statement?

Tags: c#

I have a button called 'green' I was wondering if it was possible to use this click event in an if statement? So if the button is clicked it would perform something..

This is what I have tried.

```
if (green_Click)
{
GreenScore = GreenScore + 10;
}
```

It comes up with an error saying "cannot assign to green_click because it is a 'method group'

Comment: You need to subscribe to the click event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx

Comment: Just double click the button in the designer, and it will attach an event with the button. Write that code in your event handler.

Comment: Are you sure that the error states `cannot assign to green_Click`? Because here you're not assigning to it. The error should be something like `cannot convert method group to bool. did you mean to invoke it instead?`

Answer (score 2):

In your class definition, you have something like this:

```
private Button green;    
public int GreenScore {get; set;}
```

In your form load, you would have this assignment which adds a click event listener to your `green` button.

```
green.Click += green_Click;
```

Elsewhere in your form class, you would define this method to receive the `green` button click events, where you would adjust your `GreenScore`.

```
protected void green_Click(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    GreenScore += 10;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio, just double-click the button in the designer.  It will create the event handler code for you, where you can just write your code.

Comment: Otherwise, when the control is selected, click on the Lightning Bolt next to the Properties Wrench within the properties window of that control. Then double click the event you wish to use.